# unable to authorize using Facebook ios sdk v3 when FB Native App is installed in the device

Tags: ios, facebook

Hi Guys I am having  a problem with the Facebook ios SDK 3.0.6 beta . I have created a Project using this Facebook SDK and was working ok till the Facebook native iPhone App was not installed.
When I installed the Facebook App I can no longer authorize my App. When I try to authorize, the authorization is done in the Facebook's native app instead of Safari. I get an error "The operation couldn't be completed.(com.facebook.FBiOSSDK error 2.)"

I am also receiving this error url:

fb4*********2://authorize#error_description=Invalid%2BIOS%2Bbundle%2BID&error=unknown%5Ferror

How can I solve this problem? any idea?

I am using xcode 4.2 in OSX Snow Leopard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like your settings under developer.facebook.com for the app is incorrect.

Make sure that under your app settings that;

"iOS bundle ID" under "Native iOS App" is set to your apps package name. That way the native app know which app to redirect back to once auth is complete.

Comment: Would appreciate a +1 on my answer please :)

Comment: Do I need to change the bundle in Xcode project setting or leave it as default?

Comment: @MohamMadSalah: You should write the bundle Id same as your Xcode project settings while creating facebook App.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem like you, I double check my iOS Bundle ID as Pork said and found a missed letter, after fixing it works ok.
So, check your iOS Bundle ID in your Facebook app settings for Native iOS App is 'exactly' the same as in your Bundle identifier defined in XCode for your target app.